# Задача по sql отличники/двоечники

Tags: sql

Есть табличка из двух столбцов - имя ученика и оценка. В таблице имена могут повторяться как и оценки. Задача: найдите имена и количество двоек у тех учеников, у которых больше 10 пятерок. Соответственно надо получить табличку с именем и количеством двоек. При этом нужно сделать это без подзапросов!

```
select [name], count(mark) as cnt 
from school 
where mark = '2' 
and [name] in (select [name] 
               from school 
               where mark ='5' 
               group by [name] 
               having count(mark) >= 10) 
group by [name]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И что вы уже попытались сами изобразить, что у вас не получилось? Вроде сразу какие-то варианты с `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `SUM` и `CASE` наклёвываются.

Comment: Да, но у меня только с подзапросами получается

Comment: Ну приведите в вопросе свой неправильный вариант, чтобы было видно, что вы хотя бы попытались. Халявщиков тут не любят, нужно показать, что вы пытались решить.

Comment: select [name], count(mark) as cnt from school
where mark = '2' and [name] in (select [name] from school where mark ='5' group by [name] having count(mark) >= 10)
group by [name]

Comment: можете убрать подзапрос вообще. Оставить из подзапроса только having добавив его в основной запрос и поиграться еще как то с sum(case mark = 5 then 1 ...) , если не получится - пишите, дам более развернутый ответ

Comment: Спасибо, вы натолкнули меня на верную мысль и я смог, не то что предыдущий комментатор

Comment: Ну не знаю, я вам все ключевые слова перечислил, которые нужно было использовать. Хорошо, что в итоге разобрались.

Answer (score 1):

```
select [name], sum(case when mark = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from school
group by [name] having sum(case when mark = 5 then 1 else 0 end) >= 10
```