# Задача про учеников, у которых надо подсчитать кол-во двоек!

Tags: sql, postgresql, mysqli

Задача: Необходимо вывести имя и количество двоек, у тех людей, у которых больше десяти 5. Учитывая что те кто имеют десять 5, могут не иметь двоек. Как делать так чтоб у тех у кого нет двоек, был 0 например??
По итогу выполнения кода ниже, получаю имя и количество двоек, но не людей, у которых нет двоек

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT name
    FROM marks
    WHERE mark = 5
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(mark) > 10
    )
    
    SELECT m1.name, COUNT(m1.mark)
    FROM marks m1
    JOIN t1 ON t1.name = marks.name
    WHERE mark = 2
    GROUP BY m1.name;
`
```

Comment: postgresql и mysqli - они кагбэ не очень совмещаются... *Как делать так чтоб* Использовать условное агрегирование.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374706 это оно?

Comment: @Lem0nti задача то та, но там не учитывается доп. условие если нет двоек! Уже решилось! Ответили в комментарии ниже!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Чтоб не исчезали имена без двоек, нужно использовать `LEFT`/`RIGHT`, а не `INNER` `JOIN`.
2. Чтоб заменить `NULL` на 0 можно использовать `COALESCE`.

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT name
    FROM marks
    WHERE mark = 5
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(mark) > 10
    )
    
    SELECT m1.name, COALESCE(COUNT(m1.mark), 0)
    FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN marks m1 ON t1.name = m1.name AND m1.mark = 2
    GROUP BY m1.name;
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек) Сейчас пойду разбираться чем отличается условие в join от where. я тоже подумал что нужно по хорошему соединить через left, но писал всегда where!